# Nested array of objects in a React table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, html-table

I have the following data structure that I am trying to render in a table in React.
However I keep getting a undefined issue getting the 'errors' nested array.

#### My data is the following:

```
const messages= [
  { invoice: "81", errors: [{ Message: "Invoice # must be unique." }] },
  { invoice: "82", errors: [{ Message: "Invoice # must be unique." },
                            { Message: "No total amount." }]},
  { invoice: "85", errors: [{ Message: "Invoice # must be unique." }] }
 ];
```

#### My React table is the following:

```
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Invoice</th>
    <th>Errors</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
   {messages.map(e => {
    return (
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>{e.invoice}</td>
        {messages.errors.map(e => {
         return (
          <td>
           <ul>{e.errors}</ul>
          </td>
          );
       })}
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     );
    })}
 </table>
```

My table is rendered and e.invoice is displaying corrrectly, however I am getting a  "cannot map errors of undefined" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your messages is not a javascript object, rather it's an array

You need to use

```
{e.errors.map(item => {
     return (
      <td>
       <ul>{item.Message}</ul>
      </td>
      );
})}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

`{e.errors.map(error => {` is the correct chain.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!